# Need to know about this mt4 indicator

Tags: pine-script, mql4, mt4

Could you please help me to search this indicator, please help me to know the name of the mt4 indicator.[image]

Comment: The candles look like Heikin-Ashi candles, however it is very difficult to tell from such a poor screen shot. Do you have code you can post or a full chart screen?

Comment: @PaulB Sorry for the screen shot, this is not the main chart, this is used just like RSI/MACD and so on, If you click on image, on the right hand side you will see numbers, now if the candle touches 6 and on the main chart if the trend is in down, you can make a sell position and if the candle touches -6 and it the trend is up, you can make buy position, this indicator is useful for a pullback, and this is the purchased version so I don't have a code, however, I'm trying to find about the indicator and maybe will create same in tradingview.

Comment: Can't really tell anything from that screenshot, would need more information